# Oracle DB change XML Datatypes in CLOB

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

im crushing my head over a specific Problem, where i couldnt really find anything.
Backstory: we have XML Configs saved in CLOB in an Oracle Database. However, we switched the system to a new one. I need to change all the `<long>` to `<int>` after the Attribute "Relative".
For Demonstration:
This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- SERIALIZER="XSTREAM" --><map>
  <entry>
    <string>CalendarMaintenance</string>
    <map>
      <entry>
        <string>date</string>
        <censored>
          <dbiObjectKey>0</dbiObjectKey>
          <dbiObjectState>C</dbiObjectState>
          <persistentState>0</persistentState>
          <id>date</id>
**          <value>
            <string>Relative</string>
            <long>30</long>
            <long>30</long>
          </value>**
          <sortCriteria>1</sortCriteria>
          <notRequest>false</notRequest>
          <nullRequired>false</nullRequired>
          <satisfiableCondition>true</satisfiableCondition>
        </censored>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </entry>
</map>
```

needs to be changed to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- SERIALIZER="XSTREAM" --><map>
  <entry>
    <string>CalendarMaintenance</string>
    <map>
      <entry>
        <string>date</string>
        <censored>
          <dbiObjectKey>0</dbiObjectKey>
          <dbiObjectState>C</dbiObjectState>
          <persistentState>0</persistentState>
          <id>date</id>
**          <value>
            <string>Relative</string>
            <int>30</int>
            <int>30</int>
          </value>**
          <sortCriteria>1</sortCriteria>
          <notRequest>false</notRequest>
          <nullRequired>false</nullRequired>
          <satisfiableCondition>true</satisfiableCondition>
        </censored>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </entry>
</map>
```

so in short, the long tags need to be changed to int after the  Relative Part.
Problem is also, that it could be either one tag or two.

Anyone got any ideas for this? OR anyone got experience in Regexp_replace or XML Functions in oracle?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried multiple Solutions with update Statements.
I tried with regexp_replace and an XML Function, though i have no idea in both.
This one only works for two long tags:

```
update table_name 
set column_name = regexp_replace(column_name, '<value>(\s+)<string>Relative</string>(\s+)<long>([0-9a-zA-Z]+)</long>(\s+)<long>([0-9a-zA-Z]+)</long>', '<value>\1<string>Relative</string>\2<int>\3</int>\4<int>\5</int>')
where regexp_like(column_name, '<long>([0-9]+)</long>');
```

This one works with an XML function but doesnt return the WHOLE input XML (as seen above)

```
update table_name
    set column_name = regexp_replace(
        EXTRACT(XMLTYPE.createXML(column_name), '//value[string="Relative"]/long'),
        '<long>([0-9a-zA-Z]+)</long>',
        '<int>\1</int>')
    where
        regexp_like(column_name, '<long>([0-9]+)</long>');
```

output is this:

```
<int>30</int><int>30</int>
```

Answer (score 4):

**NEVER** use string functions to parse XML; always use a proper XML parser.

You can use a FLOWR expression to rewrite the XML:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET xml = XMLSERIALIZE(
            CONTENT XMLQUERY(
              'copy $e := .
              modify (
              for $i in $e/map/entry/map/entry/censored/value[string="Relative"]/long
                return rename node $i as "int"
              )
              return $e'
              PASSING XMLTYPE(xml) RETURNING CONTENT
            ) AS CLOB
          );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (xml) AS
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- SERIALIZER="XSTREAM" --><map>
  <entry>
    <string>CalendarMaintenance</string>
    <map>
      <entry>
        <string>date</string>
        <censored>
          <dbiObjectKey>0</dbiObjectKey>
          <dbiObjectState>C</dbiObjectState>
          <persistentState>0</persistentState>
          <id>date</id>
          <value>
            <string>Relative</string>
            <long>30</long>
            <long>30</long>
          </value>
          <sortCriteria>1</sortCriteria>
          <notRequest>false</notRequest>
          <nullRequired>false</nullRequired>
          <satisfiableCondition>true</satisfiableCondition>
        </censored>
      </entry>
    </map>
  </entry>
</map>' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the table will contain:

| XML |
| --- |
| <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- SERIALIZER="XSTREAM" --><map><entry><string>CalendarMaintenance</string><map><entry><string>date</string><censored><dbiObjectKey>0</dbiObjectKey><dbiObjectState>C</dbiObjectState><persistentState>0</persistentState><id>date</id><value><string>Relative</string><int>30</int><int>30</int></value><sortCriteria>1</sortCriteria><notRequest>false</notRequest><nullRequired>false</nullRequired><satisfiableCondition>true</satisfiableCondition></censored></entry></map></entry></map> |

If you want to replace `long` tags that are children of any `value` tag (rather than on a specific path) then replace the XPATH `$e/map/entry/map/entry/censored/value[string="Relative"]/long` with `$e//value[string="Relative"]/long`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vBMEDYGy)

If you only want to update siblings *after* the `string` element then you can use the XPATH `$e//value/string[text()="Relative"]/following-sibling::long`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JRkRiHwU)

Comment: It would be better to use [`rename`  expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-rename) directly to preserve node content (attributes, comments etc.) and follow renaming requirement context: `rename node $i as "int"`

Comment: Thank you very much! I copied the stuff from fiddle and on my DB it works. However, with the actual data in my DB, it doesnt work. What does the CREATE TABLE table_name (xml) do? 
i Tried with
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = XMLQUERY(
            'copy $e := .
            modify (
            for $i in $e/map/entry/map/entry/censored/value[string="Relative"]/long
              return rename node $i as "int"
            )
            return $e'
            PASSING XMLTYPE(column_name) RETURNING CONTENT
          ).getClobVal();
Or how else do i use the column?  Sorry

Comment: i know it sound stupid, but the XML is stored in a column defined as CLOB. What could i do there?

Comment: maybe if i somehow add this, it could help?  XMLTYPE.createXML(column_name)

Comment: @W33SY `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` creates a table using the data provided in the `SELECT` statement to populate the rows of the table. If you already have a table in your database then you do not need to do that but everyone else, who does not have your data, will have to create a table.

Comment: The example above already uses a `CLOB` column; there is nothing that you should need to do (other than change the column from `xml` to `column_name`, like you did in your first comment); the query should work (and does in the linked [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aW0OcgZu)). If you are having issues with it then you need to provide a [MRE] which replicates your problems so that we can debug them.

Comment: @MT0 Alright thanks. I have tried with this statement 
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = XMLQUERY(
            'copy $e := .
            modify (
            for $i in $e//value[string="Relative"]/long
              return rename node $i as "int"
            )
            return $e'
            PASSING XMLTYPE(column_name) RETURNING CONTENT
          ).getClobVal();
But i get following errors
[Error] Execution (4: 18): 
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @W33SY If you can generate a fiddle with some sample data and a query that replicates the problem then we can help you debug it. However, the error message is that there is a problem with the call to `XMLType` which suggests that your XML is not valid so the first thing you need to do is check that you have well-formed XML.

Comment: @MT0 thanks! Alright, will create a fiddle. And appreciate it a lot

Comment: @W33SY Note that `getClobVal()` method of XMLType was [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/whatsnew.htm#ADXDB5941) in 11.2. Use `xmlserialize(content xmlquery(...) as clob)`

Comment: @astentx alright, thanks. Have tried that too. get the same error. NEed to dig into it

Comment: I Find it kind of weird @MT0 because i have kinda rebuild this scenario in Fiddle. IT works in Fiddle. I know that we use Oracle 19. https://dbfiddle.uk/sMeeyQ8O i will have to need to dig even further because i think there is something wrong on our side.